# What should I do if new breaker buzzes like the old one?

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair, circuit-breaker

Power went out in two of our bedrooms. Went to the box and found that that breaker was buzzing when turned on (but no power to rooms). So, I replaced the breaker with an identical one, but it still buzzes and doesn't work.

What else can I do? Really trying not to pay for an electrician.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-15-Amp-Single-Pole-Circuit-Breaker-HOM115CP/100153952

[image]

Comment: Turn it off.  Breakers not suppose to buzz.  Have a problem in the panel or the circuit.  Check all outlets and lights on that circuit.  Check each outlet and light with a non contact tester and/or multi meter for power before removing.

Comment: Can you clamp the circuit and measure the current? I bet it's high.  Are any boxes warmer than they should be?  Then leave the breaker turned off.  Did anything else in the house shut down that you aren't already aware of? Particularly keep an eye on freezers and fridges.

Comment: I like that the ONE circuit that is labelled has a spelling mistake.

Comment: @AdamBarnes Oh, I read that as "bolter", which I assumed was some obscure workshop equipment…

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica or a boiler ! "Contactor" for boilers also buzzes sometimes, due to high load. Well... no. --  since the boiler is already (mis-)labelled

Comment: I was surprised to see that you had to plug https://deccahome.com/bolier/ in - perhaps that explains the high price tag...

Answer (score 16):

Take the breaker out of the panel and install it in another slot. The exiting slot might be damaged or lose. If the buzzing stops, it would be to your advantage to have the panel checked out. Until you get it checked out, remove the breaker  knockout from the cover so you can put the cover back on and get a filler plate to cover the opening from the old breaker. Don't install a breaker in that old slot.

Comment: Or reinstall the original burnt breaker "as a filler plate" turned off & with no wires connected to it, and a note not to use that space. You already have it, and if the slot's damaged the breaker is probably also damaged, so let it fill the slot. Move the wire to the new breaker in a new slot.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yes to the note but I think the empty slot with a filler plate is more permanent and less likely to be ignored.

Comment: Point being, John already has, in hand, a probably damaged breaker that is of no use other than as a filler, and almost certainly does not have a filler plate without making a special trip to go buy one.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  OK. I'll give you the convenience of not having to make a trip to get a filler plate.  I'd feel bad if he went to the store and caught covid.

Comment: I have a breaker that buzzes whenever I turn on my roof heating cables... so I would take that to be a sign that you are close to the rated current for that circuit.  It's time to also check your loads.

Comment: So I tried all the above. Realized that it wasn't actually the breaker that was buzzing, but rather, the doorbell chime unit that was also spliced to it. So, next up, I'm going to check the outlet receptacles in the office. If that doesn't work, then it's beyond me and I'll just call an electrician.